# How do I get data from a pandas dataframe to the format needed for a highcharts treemap?

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, highcharts

I am trying to create a highcharts treepmap from data I pulled from this table https://www.bls.gov/news.release/empsit.t17.htm#.

I have the data in a pandas dataframe in the following format: Three columns (The parent industry, The industry, and the total number of people in that industry).

Example of my data

```
|      Parent Industry     |     Industry   |    Count of Employees   |
|--------------------------|----------------|-------------------------|
|          Total Nonfarm   |   Total Private  |     3456              |
|          Total Private   | Goods-Producing   |     1200             |         
|    Good-Producing        | Mining and Logging|      365             |
```

The data needs to be in json format as seen in this example: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/world-mortality.json as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset

I think this is what I want my json to look like, my concern is that if it is formatted like this I lose the employee count for the parent industries? I think? Unless highcharts handles that sum counts for each parent:

```
{
    "Total Nonfarm": {
        "Total Private": {
              "Goods-Producing": {
                   "Mining and Logging": {
                         "Employees": 365,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
```

This is an example from the highcharts if that helps?

```
{
    "Eastern Mediterranean": {
        "Afghanistan": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": 102.5,
            "Injuries": 47,
            "Noncommunicable diseases": 110.4
        },
        "Bahrain": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": 0.2,
            "Injuries": 0.3,
            "Noncommunicable diseases": 2.7
        },
        "Djibouti": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": 3.4,
            "Injuries": 0.7,
            "Noncommunicable diseases": 3.1
        },
```

My question is, how do I convert the dataframe I have to the json format that is required? I've tried the basic

```
data.to_json(orient="records", lines=True)
```

But that isnt the correct format.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm still kind of new to this all!

Comment: please add a sample of your dataframe .

Comment: @JonathanLeon   I added the first 2 rows of my dataframe. The Parent industry column refers to which industry the industry in the industry column belongs to. So the item in the industry column is the sub-industry belonging to the Parent Industry Column.

Comment: how about mocking up the output json you want. it's not helpful if the input data and output data have no relation and don't have the same number of fields.

Comment: @JonathanLeon I added what I think the json should look like. Initially my concern was that formatting this way I would lose the total employee counts for the parent industries, but I think I need to handle that separately when writing the javascript code for the highcharts treemap, which is an entirely separate issue.

Comment: Looking at the website and what you want as output, I'd be hard-pressed to find you a solution right out of pandas. someone with more experience might be able to get you the code you need. I'd recommend closing this question and post a new one that has your dataframe in it as no one is really going to code getting the data. And then show just your mocked up json. as mentioned, with the data and the expected output, you might get a better response to your question. good luck.